# student scores ranking or positioning on mysqli

Tags: mysql, rank

I have a MySQL table (named "scores") where I save student scores and I want to get each student Rank using total score column which I successfully did.

Below is my code:

```sql
SELECT studentRegNo, 
       subject_Id, 
       total, 
       FIND_IN_SET( total, 
                    ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( total ORDER BY total DESC ) 
                      FROM scores ) ) AS rank
FROM scores;
```

But I want the rank of each student separately based of each subject_Id
Like this:

| total | studentRegNo | subject_Id | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 86 | STM/2022/1 | 3 | 1 |
| 84 | STR/2021/3 | 3 | 2 |
| 98 | STM/2022/1 | 7 | 1 |
| 85 | STR/2021/3 | 7 | 2 |
| 85 | STM/2022/4 | 7 | 2 |
| 70 | STR/2021/5 | 7 | 4 |

Comment: What's wrong with `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY subject_Id ORDER BY total DESC)`

Comment: Provide source data which produces desired output. AS CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. Also specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: Thanks for your comment sir. I am using MySQL version 5.7 which does not recognize rank() over function

Comment: `RANK()` is not available until MySQL 8.0 or MariaDB 10.2.